# Does xdmp:database-restore overwrite any existing information in a database?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Does `xdmp:database-restore` overwrite any existing information in a MarkLogic database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; the forests specified will be returned to the exact state they were in when the backup was created.